# Adding background-image urls at nth position in url list using CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I have a `.blended-bg-image` class which shall blend two background images urls.

```
.blended-bg-image {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 100%);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 50% 50%;
   background-blend-mode: normal;
}
```

Normally i would list the urls sequentially. 
The problem is, that the second background-image url need's to be set dynamically as an inline style (rendered by vuejs).

```
<div class="blended-bg-image" style="background-image: url('/image_to_be_blended.jpg)'">
...
</div>
```

How can i add the the second background-image url to the list of the existing url's without overriding the background-image property of the elements class?

Is there a way to access the nth background-image url WITHOUT javascript?

Comment: you would have to put them all inline in the order you wanted them

Comment: thanks Pete, thats what i've done so far. thought there would be a smarter solution. problem is, that this workaround bloats the html when using an many elements.

Comment: Unfortunate side effect - one other way would be to have three divs - lower one with first style background, then your second with the dynamic one and the third one with the remainder - think that would be the same order of layering?  But then it's a toss up between the extra html bloat vs the extra styles bloat